# How to create a new org-mode file everyday automatically with contents from the previous file?

Tags: org-mode

I am learning emacs and trying to switch my note taking to org-mode from just using pen and paper. I came across [an article](http://almostobsolete.net/daypage.html) on making Org create a new day page every day. I find that very interesting because it closely reflects what I do with my notepad today...

Could someone help me figure out how to configure Org to transfer all tasks (except for those marked as "DONE") to the new day page from the previous one when it creates it? Thanks!

Comment: Save or copy the file using a new name, and in the new file, delete the entries marked done or archive them .... Look up archiving done tasks on Google and/or in the org-mode manual ... and there are probably threads about deleting ... if you search `org-cut-subtree` with some other keywords that are applicable, that should put you on the right track.  There is probably examples of how to archive or delete all done tasks ...

Comment: Here is a link to a duplicate post on reddit, in the event anyone is interested in reading what the comments/answers over there are:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/81l50r/orgmode_new_daily_page/?st=jeaygdbc&sh=4aadd8f6